# Magento Cpanel Cron Job not working

Tags: magento, cron, server, cpanel, jobs

I cant get the Cron Job set up on our server to send out password resets and email confirmations. Have I set it up correctly? Have tried many different ways - the latest being:

curl -L -s http://www.****.com/cron.php

*/5 *   *   *   *

Is this right? Ideally I'd like to set it to instant for now so I can see if is working, then change to every 5 minutes.

**Update: I've been told by our server provider it has been set up properly, so is there anything within Magento I should check?**

Thanks.

Comment: you are try this command on shell? I usually use */5 * * * * php -f /home/USER/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1. It's possible that your hosting block curl, wget, and other programs for normal users.

Comment: ive been trying to stick to cpanel to set it up as i'm not too familar with using terminal/command line. I'll give the command you gave a go though.

Comment: You need learn some aboput shell. For debug pourposes, for too many cmmandas or mantenace of magento,

Comment: I've phoned our server provider and they've set it up correctly. Still not getting emails though, so can you suggest anything to check within magento?

Comment: You need know what it's problem. 1.- First need if problem it's cron 2. Check if problem it's command 3. Check logs you are sure that curl it's installed and not on on disable_functions ? test vcreate a file named info.php qith a <? phpinfo();  and see if curl it's enable or disable. Try also with */5 * * * * php -f /home/USER/public_html/cron.php usin php instead curl

Comment: install this extension and check its working or not : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: have just installed that and all have come back green each time the cron fires :/